# WPF Margin renders differently on windows XP / 7

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

[image: Render diff]

I have tried the hack located at http://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/ but it had no effect on this problem, there might be some ScaleTransform involved here but the value of it is the same in both pictures.
Does any one know why there is such a big difference and is there any way to fix it?

Here is the style of the button:

```
<Style x:Key="activityButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,0,3" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pushedBorder">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pushedBorder2">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pushedBorder3">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pushedBorder">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pushedBorder2">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pushedBorder3">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    <Border x:Name="normalBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.5"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#19000000" Offset="0.51"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="pushedBorder4" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.5"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#19000000" Offset="0.51"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="pushedBorder"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#33000000" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <Border x:Name="pushedBorder2"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#33000000" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <Border x:Name="pushedBorder3"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#33000000" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Although this is not a good answer I don't think this is something worse spending time on. WinXP is going to disappear in 2 years for ever(almost). I would file this as a bug and come back to it when and if needed. But if you want you can as another alternative to use conditional compilation directive in your XAML (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blemmon/archive/2009/04/29/using-the-preprocessor-to-share-incompatible-xaml-between-sl-and-wpf-part-1.aspx) or code.